# Data detector for number 1 and 0

Tags: python, list, detection

I have a data set containing with only 0 and 1. I want to have a detector to find where 1 starts and where 1 ends, and then return something related to their index to a different list each. So I've written some codes as below:

```
n= [1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1,
    1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]

def detector (data):
    x = 0
    start = []
    end = []
    for index, i in enumerate(data):
        if x == 0 and i == 1: 
            start.append((index+1))
            x == 1
        elif x == 1 and i==0:
                end.append((index))
                x == 0
    return start, end

print (detector(n))
```

However when I run the code above, it returned like below, which is not my desired output.

```
([1, 2, 3, 4, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38], [])
```

My desired output is as below:

```
([1, 22, 34], [4,28,38])
```

As you can see above, the start_time should be[1,22,34] and end_time should be [4,28,38].

If anyone knows how to solve the issue, pls let me know. Appreciated!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One issue is certainly, that you dont change flag.
== is a comparison operator and does not assign a new value to flag

Comment: Oh could you pls explain how to change the value of the flag? I think if I can change it then my problem will be solved.

Comment: `flag = 1` instead of `flag == 1`. You code then works except for catching the final end_time

Comment: But when I do `flag = 1`, it gives me an syntax error?

Comment: which flag == 1 are you chaging? DOnt change the ones in the if condition, changes the ones after appending into start/end times

Comment: Ohh yea I got it! Lol what a silly mistake. Thanks a lot!

Comment: One more question that if I also want to catch the final end_time, is there any way to do it?

Comment: after the for loop, you can check whether the last number was a 1. In that case you want to append the length of the numbers minus 1 to end_time,
because the length of the numbers minus 1 is the index of the last number

Answer (score 1):

using [`enumerate`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#enumerate) to get positions of `1`s and [`zip`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#zip) to find when sequence of consecutive `1`s starts/ends

```
ones_positions = [position
                  for position, value in enumerate(n)
                  if value == 1]
ones_starts = [ones_positions[0]] + [
    next_position
    for position, next_position in zip(ones_positions,
                                       ones_positions[1:])
    if next_position - position > 1]
ones_ends = [position
             for position, next_position in zip(ones_positions,
                                                ones_positions[1:])
             if next_position - position > 1] + [ones_positions[-1]]
```

gives us

```
>>>ones_starts
[0, 21, 33]
>>>ones_ends
[3, 27, 37]
```

we can specify `enumerate`'s `start` parameter if you want your indices to start from `1` (when they are naturally start from `0`)

```
ones_positions = [position
                  for position, value in enumerate(n, start=1)
                  if value == 1]
```

after that

```
>>>ones_starts
[1, 22, 34]
>>>ones_ends
[4, 28, 38]
```

Finally we can write it as function:

```
def detector(data, target_value=1):
    positions = [position
                 for position, value in enumerate(data, start=1)
                 if value == target_value]
    start_times = [positions[0]] + [
        next_position
        for position, next_position in zip(positions,
                                           positions[1:])
        if next_position - position > 1]
    end_times = [position
                 for position, next_position in zip(positions,
                                                    positions[1:])
                 if next_position - position > 1] + [positions[-1]]
    return start_times, end_times
```

and test

```
n = [1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1,
     1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]
print(detector(n))
```

gives us

```
([1, 22, 34], [4, 28, 38])
```

Answer (score 0):

You could also try using groupby:

```
import itertools
L = [[y[0] for y in it] 
     for x,it in
     itertools.groupby(enumerate(n),lambda x: x[1])
     ][::2]
res = [x[0] for x in L],[x[-1] for x in L]
```

You could probably arrive at an even more correct solution without using indexes.

Thanks to vishes_shell for the correction

Comment: Output is different from OP's expected.

Comment: Yeah I should have read what OP needed a bit more carefully. The idea was to use groupby and not explicit indexes. I'll edit it. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
n = [1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1,
     1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]

prev_num = 0

starts = []
ends = []
result = (starts, ends)

for idx, num in enumerate(n):
    if prev_num == 0 and num == 1:
        starts.append(idx + 1)
    elif prev_num == 1 and num == 0:
        ends.append(idx + 1)
    elif num == 1 and idx == (len(n) - 1):
        ends.append(idx + 1)
    prev_num = num

print(result)
```

Which prints:

```
[[1, 22, 34], [5, 29, 38]]
```

Answer (score 0):

Since @DanielChristiany pointed you where your mistake was. I will present you my solution which is faster than any of presented(at least that works correctly):

```
edges = (index for index, i in enumerate(n[1:], 1) if i != n[index-1])
if n[0] == 1:
    edges = (1, *edges)
if n[-1] == 1:
    some = (*edges, len(n))
print(edges[::2], edges[1::2])
```

Basically it firstly searches edges where element changes from 0 to 1 or from 1 to 0. Then checks if first and last elements are 1 and then print result.

This solution also uses less memory since it uses generators.